# htaccess redirect not exist file and show link like exist

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NS,R,L]
RewriteRule ^((?:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]|%20)+)/?$ member.php?id=$1
```

With this htaccess, i can remove .php and i can show my "example.com/member.php?id=1" page as "example.com/3".

Now i want to show "example.com/product.php?id=1" as "example.com/product/1" but the interesting part, there is not exist "product" file. Is it possible to show as "example.com/product/1"?

Thanks

Comment: Why not redirecting everything to index.php and routing it internally from there?

Comment: @EnricoDias but i have to show example.com/member.php as a example.com/3. With your suggestion is it possible?

Comment: If you redirect everything to index.php you can include any page you want based on the requested uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# product rewrite
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# member rewrite
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ member.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works but i see some css problem on product/1 pages. How can i fix that?

Comment: For css issues add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`